任意のドライブの下にあるフォルダの権限を表示したい
以下の投稿を参考に、任意のドライブの下にあるフォルダの権限を表示しようとしていますが、rootドライブしか表示されません。
任意のドライブの表示をするにはどのように変更すべきでしょうか？
Googleドライブの各フォルダのメンバー情報をスプシに一覧表示させたい
const act_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
let drv_list, drv_info, drv_token;
let prm_list, prm_info, role_ja;
let array = [];

function myFunction() {
  array.push(["共有ドライブ", "メンバー", "メール", "タイプ", "役割"]);

  // Drive APIから共有ドライブのリストを取得、pageTokenがある限り繰り返し
  do {
    drv_list = Drive.Drives.list({
      maxResults: 300,
      pageToken: drv_token,
      useDomainAdminAccess: true
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < drv_list.drives.length
  ; i++) {
      drv_info = drv_list.drives[i];
    

      try {
          // 共有ドライブごとにパーミッション情報を取得
        prm_list = Drive.Permissions.list(
          drv_info.id,
          {supportsAllDrives: true, useDomainAdminAccess: true}
        );
      
        for (let j = 0; j < prm_list.permissions.length; j++) {
          prm_info = prm_list.permissions[j];

          // ロール情報を日本語化
          switch (prm_info.role) {
            case ("organizer"):
              role_ja = "管理者";
              break;
            case ("fileOrganizer"):
              role_ja = "コンテンツ管理者";
              break;
            case ("reader"):
              role_ja = "閲覧者";
              break;
            case ("commenter"):
              role_ja = "閲覧者（コメント可）";
              break;
            case ("writer"):
              role_ja = "投稿者";
              break;
            default:
              role_ja = prm_info.role;
          }

          // 取得した共有ドライブ名および各種情報を配列に追加
          if (j === 0) {
            array.push([
              drv_info.name, 
              prm_info.displayName, prm_info.emailAddress, prm_info.type, role_ja
            ]);
          } else {
            array.push([
              "",  // 出力形式上、最初のメンバー以外の配列には共有ドライブ名不要
              prm_info.displayName, prm_info.emailAddress, prm_info.type, role_ja
            ]);
          }
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        array.push([err]);
        continue;
      }
    }
    drv_token = drv_list.nextPageToken;
  } while (drv_token);

  // 配列をGoogleシートに反映
  act_sheet.clear();
  act_sheet.setFrozenRows(1);
  act_sheet.getRange(1, 1, array.length, array[0].length).setValues(array);
}

